# Do NVidia 3D Vision glasses work in XpanD theatres?

Tags: 3d-vision

Do NVidia 3D Vision glasses work in XpanD theatres?

My local theatre is equipped both with Dolby 3D, which I personally appreciate most, and with XpanD. I just bought a 3D Vision kit to play games, and since XpanD is shutter-glasses based, I wonder if anyone ever tried to sit in the theatre with his own NVidia glasses and see if they work with XpanD. I might try by myself, but they are not currently playing 3D movies I might like :) (and it costs €10 to watch a 3D movie here hehehe)

PS: by the way, does anybody know if NVidia 3D Vision glasses work with other 3D systems, such as current [*expensive*] 3D TVs? Just to know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D Vision is a closed platform, will only work with Nvidia based systems. You wont be able to work it in a theater, or with 3D TVs.

Xpand just release Universal 3D Glasses that work with all 3D IR based systems, except 3D Vision since it is closed platform.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an experiment you'll have to try.

I would expect all shutter glasses work on the same principle - that a transmitter above or below the screen sends a syncing signal to the glasses so that the left and right lenses are opened and closed at the right time.

However, I wouldn't be surprised if each system used a different signal so that your nVidia glasses won't react to the XpanD signal or 3D TV signal and vice versa.